# How do I include mkl_vsl modules for random number generators e.g. 'vsrnggaussian'? (Fortran)

Tags: random, fortran, gfortran, intel-mkl

I'm new to Fortran (gfortran on windows) and want to use the random number generator `vsrnggaussian`.

`vsrnggaussian` needs the Intel MKL VSL modules 'mkl_vsl_type' and 'mkl_vsl' which are provided in the mkl_vsl.f90 file. This file needs to be included to generate the module files 'mkl_vsl_type.mod' and 'mkl_vsl.mod' which are used to process the Fortran use clauses referencing to the VSL interface:

```
use mkl_vsl_type
use mkl_vsl
```

I tried multiple things to include the mkl_vsl.f90 file but none of them work:

1. I inserted the file into the project directory --> 793 errors occured (can't list all of them here in detail) such as:

- `Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)`
- `[...] at (1) has no implicit type`
- `expecting [...] statement at (1)`
- `unexpected [...] statement at (1)`
- and finally `Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'mkl_vsl_type.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory. compilation terminated. "gfortran -g -o incl_mkl.exe ../incl_mkl.f90" terminated with exit code 1. Build might be incomplete.`

2. I used the full path in the include statement: `INCLUDE 'C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146/windows/mkl/include/mkl_vsl.f90'` --> `Error: Can't open included file`
3. I tried the -Idir compiler command: `gfortran -I/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146/windows/mkl/include/ -g -o incl_mkl.exe` --> `gfortran: error: Files: no such file or directory`
4. I put this into the makefile: `INCLUDES=-I. -I/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146/windows/mkl/include/` --> `Error: Can't open included file`

How do I include the mkl_vsl.f90 file??

edit: my simple code to include the mkl_vsl.f90 file
(this code will be compiled first before i compile my main code with `vsrnggaussian`):

```
Program INCL
IMPLICIT NONE
INCLUDE 'mkl_vsl.f90'
!INCLUDE 'C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146/windows/mkl/include/mkl_vsl.f90'
END Program
```

Comment: Please tell us what "multiple incomprehensible errors" are - even if you don't understand them most likely somebody else here will. Even better also include a short, *complete* code that shows what problems you are having - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're also likely to want to use quotes to protect that paths with spaces (`-I"/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146/windows/mkl/include/"`).

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to **USE** both `vsl_type` and `vsl` **modules**. The reason is that the derived types in `vsl` are defined in `vsl_type`. MWE

```
Program INCL
use mkl_vsl_type
use mkl
IMPLICIT NONE
write(6, *) 'hello world'
END Program
```

You would need to pass the address to file `mkl_vsl.f90` to ifort and the `mkl` flag.

```
ifort -mkl foo.f90 <address>/mkl_vsl.f90
```

For using any specific subroutine of MKL consult their website. There is also extensive examples that come with MKL. You may find it in `C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.146/windows/mkl/examples` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. I have two questions concerning this: 1) Do I have to use ifort compiler (gfortran is not possible)? 2) What's foo.f90 ?

Comment: @ToastCode This answer is not completely correct or at least not complete, in the last step , there are many subtle details that may change in the linking command. Follow the advisor https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onemkl/link-line-advisor.html Gfortran is also supported.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are using ifort. As Vladmir said, yes gfortran is supported and foo.f90 is the file you want to compile.